# Wrap long 'go:generate' lines with markers?

Tags: go

Is it possible to wrap long lines with markers in Golang?

Here's an example:

```
//go:generate mockgen -destination=mock/interface.go -package=mock -source=interface.go -mock_names=ConnPool=ConnPool,Row=Row,Rows=Rows,CommandTag=CommandTag,Conn=Conn
type ConnPool interface {
    ...    
}
```

Comment: go generate is line based; you can't break them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comments)
>
> [Comments](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comments)
>
> Comments serve as program documentation. There are two forms:
>
> 1 Line comments start with the character sequence // and stop at the end of the line.
>
> 2 General comments start with the character sequence /* and stop with the first subsequent character sequence */.
>
> A comment cannot start inside a rune or string literal, or inside a
>   comment. A general comment containing no newlines acts like a space.
>   Any other comment acts like a newline.

---

No. The `//go:generate` pragma is a special form of a line comment: "Line comments start with the character sequence // and stop at the end of the line."

Answer (score 0):

you may try this way:

encode the generate command with base64

```sh
base64 <<< 'mockgen -destination=mock/interface.go -package=mock -source=interface.go -mock_names=ConnPool=ConnPool,Row=Row,Rows=Rows,CommandTag=CommandTag,Conn=Conn'
```

insert the encode content to first line of your go file with comment prefix

```golang
//bW9ja2dlbiAtZGVzdGluYXRpb249bW9jay9pbnRlcmZhY2UuZ28gLXBhY2thZ2U9bW9jayAtc291
//cmNlPWludGVyZmFjZS5nbyAtbW9ja19uYW1lcz1Db25uUG9vbD1Db25uUG9vbCxSb3c9Um93LFJv
//d3M9Um93cyxDb21tYW5kVGFnPUNvbW1hbmRUYWcsQ29ubj1Db25uCg==
```

then add decode and run generate command follow the base64 content

```golang
//go:generate sh -c "eval $(head -3 $GOFILE | tr -d '^[ ]*//[ ]*' | base64 -d)"
```

at last run `go generate yourfile.go`